# How to change or modify starting point (commit) of a git branch?

Tags: git

Let say I have following `git` structure

```
1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8 (master-branch)
                      \
                       9--10--11--12(custom-branch)
```

How can I get into the following `git` structure?

```
1--2--3--4 (master-branch)
          \
           5--6--7--8--9--10--11--12 (custom-branch)
```

Comment: A branch doesn't have a "starting point"; it's just a pointer to a single commit.  Because your question spells out "before" and "after" commit structures, it's possible to answer - and mouche's answer will get you from point A to point B. But it may also have side-effects if you've ever pushed `master-branch` to a remote, because what you're *really* doing is removing history from `master-branch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you would just checkout `master` and rewind it a few commits. `custom-branch` won't be changed.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard "HEAD~4"
```

**Warning:** Using `--hard` gets rid of any local changes. However, without it, the changes in all the commits you rewound will end up as local changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative which I feel it is safer:

```
git checkout "HEAD~4" 
git branch -f master
```

So first you put your HEAD where you want your master branch tip (commit 4)
And then you create there a branch called master (you have to force it, -f because the name already existed).

Or, if HEAD is already in master, then only:

```
git branch -f master HEAD~4
```